# Aframe and AR.js does not show my .gltf model

Tags: three.js, aframe, ar.js

i am new about aframe and arjs, i would to show my own gltf models over an hiro path, i write this code:

```
<!-- include A-Frame obviously -->
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.6.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<!-- include ar.js for A-Frame -->
<script src="https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script>

<body style='margin : 0px; overflow: hidden;'>
  <a-scene embedded arjs>
    <!-- define your gltf asset -->
    <!--This is for add a text-->
    <a-text value="Hello, World!"></a-text>
    <a-assets>
      <a-asset-item id="tree" src="models/gltf/manovella.gltf"></a-asset-item>
    </a-assets>
    <a-entity gltf-model="##tree"></a-entity>
    <!-- define a camera which will move according to the marker position -->
    <a-marker-camera preset='hiro'></a-marker-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

when i run my code and lace an hiro marker from of the cam i just see "Hello world!" text and not my own model, i check browser console error but i don't gen anything.

Someone can help me about? Where i was wrong for load my own model?

so many thanks in advance

Comment: try the [newest versions](https://github.com/AR-js-org/AR.js#-marker-based-example) of arjs and aframe, if that won't help, try viewing the model without ar.js - maybe it's huge, or off-centered.

Comment: It should be gltf-model="#tree", not "##tree", I think it's just a typo

Comment: @StéphaneAlbanese nice catch, also i think aframe 0.6.0 didn't support gltf 2.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try using A-Frame version 0.8.2. And as [Stéphane Albanese](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11669520/st%C3%A9phane-albanese) mentioned, you have an extra # in `##tree`